# Installing from source without apt-get in pythonanywhere

Tags: makefile, package, pythonanywhere

Maybe it's because I'm new to shared environments where I have no root access or the `dpkg`/`apt` family of tools, but I wanted to install from source (for instance, [gcc](http://gcc.petsads.us/releases/gcc-4.7.1/)/[gdb](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/)), possibly by using `wget` to grab the tarball, unpack it, and point `configure --prefix=$HOME`, before calling `make; make install`, but I'm having some issues. Namely, the whitelist (obvious), and secondly the configure step is giving me trouble.

Can someone walk me through this process? Pythonanywhere comes with `make`, so it's not as if they don't want you doing this.

### EDIT

Perhaps gcc/gdb may not be the best example -- together they are close to half the 500MB allotment for free accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any pure python modules will install with ease. Unfortunately you can't install modules that require a compiler. The Python Anywhere staff is generally very accommodating to get packages requested installed to the [battery's included](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/batteries_included/) for all to enjoy.

Feel free to make a request to the [PA forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/)

or

Email the staff: support@pythonanywhere.com

For clarity. To install a pure python module you just use

```
pip-3.2 install --user <package_name>
```

Change `3.2` as needed for the Python version you want and of course change `<package_name>` to your desired package.

Comment: I can't add more than that :-) Please do feel free to request packages you want installed as standard.